# How do i get the ID of a product so i can display each product in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination, modal-dialog

I have a set of products in pagination in products.php , and i when i click "Details" button, i want a modal to popup and show each product Specification that i have in products_details.php.

Page Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QMbx.jpg

My code right now only show the 5th ID of each page.
If i am at page 1, it will show A05 of that page when i click details.
If i am at page 2, it will show A10 of that page when i click details.

Below is my products.php

```
    <?php
include_once 'products_crud.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Paw Empire : Products</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <?php include_once 'nav_bar.php'; ?>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h2>Create New Product</h2>
        </div>
        <form action="products.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productid" class="col-sm-3 control-label">ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input name="pid" type="text" class="form-control" id="productid" placeholder="Product ID" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $editrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="productname" placeholder="Product Name" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $editrow['fld_product_name']; ?>" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productprice" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Price (RM)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input name="price" type="number" class="form-control" id="productprice" placeholder="Product Price" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $editrow['fld_product_price']; ?>" min="0.0" step="0.01" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productq" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantity</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input name="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" id="productq" placeholder="Product Quantity" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $editrow['fld_product_quantity']; ?>"  min="0" required>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="producttype" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <select name="type" class="form-control" id="producttype" required>
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option value="Cat" <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) if($editrow['fld_product_type']=="Cat") echo "selected"; ?>>Cat</option>
                <option value="Cat Food" <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) if($editrow['fld_product_type']=="Cat Food") echo "selected"; ?>>Cat Food</option>
                <option value="Cat Toys" <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) if($editrow['fld_product_type']=="Cat Toys") echo "selected"; ?>>Cat Toys</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>   



          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="supplier" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Supplier</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <select name="supplier" class="form-control" id="supplier" required>
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option value="My Pets Library" <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) if($editrow['fld_product_supplier']=="My Pets Library") echo "selected"; ?>>My Pets Library</option>
                <option value="Pet Lovers Centre" <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) if($editrow['fld_product_supplier']=="Pet Lovers Centre") echo "selected"; ?>>Pet Lovers Centre</option>
                <option value="Pet Smart" <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) if($editrow['fld_product_supplier']=="Pet Smart") echo "selected"; ?>>Pet Smart</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>




          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productshipping" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Shipping Price (RM)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input name="shipping" type="number" class="form-control" id="productshipping" placeholder="Shipping Price" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $editrow['fld_product_price']; ?>" min="0.0" step="0.01" required>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
              <?php if (isset($_GET['edit'])) { ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="oldpid" value="<?php echo $editrow['fld_product_num']; ?>">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Update</button>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="create"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Create</button>
              <?php } ?>
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" aria-hidden="true"></span> Clear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h2>Products List</h2>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price (RM)</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Shipping Price (RM)</th>
            <th></th>

          </tr>
          <?php
      // Read
          $per_page = 5;
          if (isset($_GET["page"]))
            $page = $_GET["page"];
          else
            $page = 1;
          $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
          try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from tbl_products_a180834_pt2 LIMIT $start_from, $per_page");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
          }
          catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
          }
          foreach($result as $readrow) {
            ?> 
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_price']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_quantity']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_type']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_supplier']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_shipping']; ?></td>


              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#exampleModal">Details</button>


                <a href="products.php?edit=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button"> Edit </a>
                <a href="products.php?delete=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <nav>
          <ul class="pagination">
            <?php
            try {
              $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
              $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
              $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products_a180834_pt2");
              $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
              $total_records = count($result);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
              echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
            ?>
            <?php if ($page==1) { ?>
              <li class="disabled"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
              <li><a href="products.php?page=<?php echo $page-1 ?>" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>
              <?php
            }
            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)
              if ($i == $page)
                echo "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"products.php?page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
              else
                echo "<li><a href=\"products.php?page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
              ?>
              <?php if ($page==$total_pages) { ?>
                <li class="disabled"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></li>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <li><a href="products.php?page=<?php echo $page+1 ?>" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
              <?php } ?>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Paw Empire : Product Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



        <script>
          $('.btn-xs').on('click',function(){
            $('.modal-body').load('products_details.php?pid=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>',function(){
              $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
            });
          });
          
        </script>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  </body>
  </html>
```

And below is my products_details.php

```
    <?php
  include_once 'database.php';
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Paw Empire : Products Details</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 
<?php include_once 'nav_bar.php'; ?>
 
<?php
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products_a180834_pt2 WHERE fld_product_num = :pid");
  $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];
  $stmt->execute();
  $readrow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 well well-sm text-center">
      <?php if ($readrow['fld_product_image'] == "" ) {
        echo "No image";
      }
      else { ?>
      <img src="products/<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_image'] ?>" class="img-responsive">
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Product Details</strong></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          Below are specifications of the product.
      </div>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><strong>Product ID</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_name'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Price (RM)</strong></td>
          <td>RM <?php echo $readrow['fld_product_price'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_quantity'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_type'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Supplier</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_supplier'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Shipping Price (RM)</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_shipping'] ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem you are facing is that `$('.modal-body').load('products_details.php?pid=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>',function(){
` is set to the last element of your `foreach` loop. You could add a `data` attribute to your details button or based on the click, grep the HTML from the event and extract the product number that way.

Comment: may i know how to do that ? i am sorry i am newbie in this

Answer (score 0):

You can put the block for modal inside the loop. In the modal content, you can show any content. Check the following code. (Updated)

```
<?php
// include_once 'products_crud.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Paw Empire : Products</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h2>Products List</h2>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price (RM)</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Shipping Price (RM)</th>
            <th></th>

          </tr>
          <?php
      
          $result = array(
            array('fld_product_num' => '12345', 'fld_product_name' => 'P One','fld_product_price' => '1000'),
            array('fld_product_num' => '123456', 'fld_product_name' => 'P Two','fld_product_price' => '2000')
          );
          
          foreach($result as $readrow) {
            ?> 
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_price']; ?></td>
              


              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>">Details</button>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Paw Empire : Product Details</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                        <?php echo $readrow['fld_product_name']; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" datadismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    




  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I cannot seems to open the modal by clicking the button after using this, do you have any clarification ? Thanks !

Comment: You have to use jquery.js and bootstrap.js to make it working. Also remove the script for button click.

Comment: I have removed the script for button click and also using jquery and bootsrap but it seems it cannot be working. Bootstrap im using is 3.3.7

Comment: The answer is updated. Result is reproduced by keeping the main portion and generating dummy array.

Comment: thank you, it worked now, but how do i show products_details.php?pid=[ID of Product]
for every products ?

Comment: If you want to show product details in a separate page, then simply redirect the product id and run query and show details.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, can you please approve it?

Comment: i want to show product details on the modal, as of right now it only shows the ID of the product.. I want to show the product details of the product ID from products_details.php